# Unable to Autowire a class, response is null

Tags: java, multithreading

I have Autowired ScheduledTaskRepository in my class. But when I am trying to execute scheduledTaskRepository.findAll() scheduledTaskRepository is null. Why this value is null?v

```
@Slf4j(topic = SCHEDULER)
public abstract class AbstractTaskOperation implements Runnable
{

/**
 * Properties.
 */
protected final Properties properties;

/**
 * Period between two successive execution of the task.
 */
private final long period;

   
private final boolean enabled;

/**
 * ScheduledTask Repository.
 */
@Autowired
private ScheduledTaskRepository scheduledTaskRepository;

  
protected AbstractTaskOperation (final Properties properties, final long period,
                        final SecretsManager secretsManager, final boolean enabled)
    this.secretsManager = secretsManager;
    this.properties = properties;
    this.period = period;
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

@Override
public void run ()
{
    log.debug("Entered run of AbstractTask Entity");
    try {
        final List<ScheduledTaskItemEntity> scheduledTaskItemIdList =
            scheduledTaskRepository.findAll();
        for (final ScheduledTaskItemEntity scheduledTaskItem : scheduledTaskItemIdList) {
                scheduledTaskRepository.save(scheduledTaskItem);
                if (conditionSatisfied(scheduledTaskItem)) {
                    performTask(scheduledTaskItem);
                }
        }
    }
```

I have Autowired ScheduledTaskRepository in my class. But when I am trying to execute scheduledTaskRepository.findAll() scheduledTaskRepository is null. Why this value is null?

Comment: You've not provided enough info. For instance, how do we know you have ComponentScan enabled? How is the `ScheduledTaskRepository` class annotated? Are you running as a SpingBootApplication or SpringApplication or running this class from the command line as Runnable suggests? etc.

Comment: I would say that you are initializing AbstractTaskOperation not through Spring but by constructor. In that case, you need to pass your repository through constructor and include this.scheduledTaskRepository = scheduledTaskRepository; inside your constructor.